# Debian 10 Read-Only filesystem Unattended Upgrades

Tags: debian, apt, readonly

I have a Debian 10 (embedded) machine that has a read-only filesystem.

The problem is that the following services fail: "apt-daily" and "apt-daily-upgrade".

I need these services, so removing them is not an option.

For DPKG, I am using a script that will temporarily make the filesystem writable, so that I can upgrade packages manually (as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#Tips_and_tricks)). Is there a similar thing that I can do for the two services described above?

Answer (score 2):

To make a normally `ro` mount `rw` for the duration of the apt-daily-update, a systemd override can be implemented on the apt-daily-update.service. I use precisely this mechanism on a normally `ro` /boot partition on a Debian 11 box.

First create the override file:

```
systemctl edit apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

Fill it with something like the following (specifying your particular target mount):

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/mount -o remount,rw /boot
ExecStartPost=-/usr/bin/mount -o remount,ro /boot
```

You can check that the mount changes from `ro` to `rw` and then back again, under upgrade circumstances, by first opening a `watch` in a terminal window.

```
watch -n1 "/usr/bin/mount -l | grep /boot"
```

From another terminal you can then initiate the `apt-daily-upgrade` as follows:

```
systemctl start apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your remount command in systemd unit file:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=-/usr/lib/apt/apt-helper wait-online #; add your remount rw here
ExecStartPost= ; add your remount ro here
```

^ this has not been tested (but should work I guess)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have also thought of this but I thought that if the 'apt' application is updated, then the updated systemd unit file is overwritten?

Comment: after an initial google search - the correct way of modifying an unit file is this: https://serverfault.com/questions/840996/modify-systemd-unit-file-without-altering-upstream-unit-file . I will update my answer.